# What is the fifth argument in this assembly loop?

Tags: c, loops, assembly, x86-64

I am learning assembly for my CIS class, and I've come across the following problem:

Consider the following x86-64 code:

```
loop:
   movq %rsi, %rcx
   movl $1, %eax
   movl $0, %edx
.L2:
   testq %rax, %rax
   je .L4
   movq %rax, %r8
   andq %rdi, %r8
   orq %r8, %rdx
   salq %cl, %rax
   jmp .L2
.L4:
   movq %rdx, %rax
   ret
```

The code above was generated by compiling C code (with Arch gcc) that has the following overall form:

```
long loop(long a, long b) {
 long result = 0;
 for (long mask = ?; mask != ?; mask <<= ?) {
 result |= (? & ?);
 }
 return result;
}
```

Copy the above x86-64 code into a C file as a comment. Annotate each line of the x86-64 code in terms of x, y, result, and mask.

Alright, so of course `%rax` is the return val, and I believe that `%rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx` are `a, b, result, mask` respectively. But the thing that confuses my is this supposed fifth argument in the code, `%r8`. Have I misunderstood what is considered an argument in assembly language, or is there something different with for loops in assembly? Any feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: The number of registers used by assembly code generated for a function does not need to be exactly the same as the number of locals and arguments in the function.

Comment: First, `mask` and `result` are *variables* not arguments.  Second, an optimizing compiler will not necessarily keep a single variable in a single register throughout the function.  Some variables might live in different registers at different times, some might get optimized completely out of existence, or registers might be used to hold temporary values that don't correspond directly to any variable.

Comment: But at a glance, it looks to me like `rax` is being used to hold `mask`, more or less; `rcx` is just a copy of `b` (needed because the shift instruction requires the shift count in `cl`); and `r8` is used to hold the result of `? & ?`.

Comment: What you are probably confused by is that while the calling convention says you should put the 5th argument into `r8` that does not mean you can't use it for your own purposes inside the function. It is just another caller-saved register. Similarly, `rcx` and `rdx` are also only used as locals. Since the function only takes 2 arguments, only `rdi` and `rsi` are used to hold them. Even those registers can be reused for other purposes once you no longer need the arguments in them.

Comment: @GovindParmar Thank you all for these comments that are sending me in the right direction! Everyone seems to be saying that the registers used is different from the number of arguments. Would someone mind explaining in an answer the difference, and what's going on in the aforementioned function?

Comment: Of course registers are different from the number of arguments. Registers are used for all the calculations done within a function.

Comment: The registers hold arguments at entry to the function, but after that, the function is permitted to use the registers for any purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after reading all these comments, I think I found the answer. It seems to be that I was misunderstanding register arguments -- thinking that they *had* to be connected to a variable in the C code. Turns out they do not. So I set aside the C code and just sat down and analyzed the assembly, and I think I've gotten it written out properly for what each step is doing (and then the equivalent C code afterwards). I would love some confirmation about that though, if anyone is able to.

Assembly Functions:

```
        %eax, %rax = RetVal
        %rdi = Arg1 = a
        %rsi = Arg2 = b
        %edx, %rdx = Arg3 = result
        %cl, %rcx = Arg4 = mask
        %r8 = Arg5

loop:
    movq %rsi, %rcx   <=> Arg4 = Arg2
    movl $1, %eax     <=> RetVal = 1
    movl $0, %edx     <=> Arg3 = 0
.L2:
    testq %rax, %rax  <=> if RetVal == 0
    je .L4            <=> go to .L4
    movq %rax, %r8    <=> Arg5 = RetVal
    andq %rdi, %r8    <=> Arg5 = (Arg5 & Arg1)
    orq %r8, %rdx     <=> Arg3 = (Arg3 | Arg5)
    salq %cl, %rax    <=> RetVal = (RetVal << Arg4)
    jmp .L2           <=> go to .L2
.L4:
    movq %rdx, %rax   <=> RetVal = Arg3
    ret               <=> return RetVal
```

Equivalent C Code(?):

```
long loop(long a, long b) {
    long result = 0;
    for (long mask = b; mask != 0; mask <<= 1) {
        result |= (mask & a);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Terminology: I think (hope...) you meant to say that arg-passing registers don't have to be used for arg-passing in functions with fewer args.  The phrase "register *arguments*" implies that we're talking about an actual function arg that *is* passed in a register.  That does have be connected to a C function arg.  (Unless it's a `...` variadic function like `printf(const char*, ...)`, then there are register args that are only accessed via VA_ARG which gets the compiler to generate code that can index into the array of integer or FP args, usually by dumping incoming regs to memory.)

Comment: It would also be more accurate to say that arg-passing registers only have that meaning on entry to the function. Your asm comment `Arg4 = Arg2` still shows a serious misunderstanding.  RCX is not "arg4", it's just RCX, an unused call-clobbered (scratch) register.  In fact it's acting as the "count" reg.  `rax<<= Arg2`.  Compilers do sometimes copy an incoming arg to a different register, e.g. in a function that makes function calls it would be normal to see a `push %rbx` / `mov %rdi, %rbx` to save it in a call-preserved register if the first arg was needed after a function call.

Comment: Similarly, RAX inside the loop is *not* where the function is keeping `result`.  Notice that it ends with `mov %rdx, %rax`, so the value it returns is the value that was in RDX.  **RAX is some other variable, *not* the return value, except at the function boundary where the calling convention specifies the meaning of registers.**  It's super misleading to comment your code this way.  Using `Arg4` or `RetVal` that way in comments is no more helpful than just using the bare register names, so why bother?  Comment with the *actual* C variables, e.g. the thing being left-shifted (RAX) is mask.

Comment: Also no, `mask <<= 1` is wrong.  The asm doesn't set `%cl` to 1, and doesn't have any shifts with a fixed count or any `add same,same`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for this very helpful feedback! Well now I am just very confused though, because my CS book calls %rax the "return value" and it calls %rdi, %rsi, etc up through I believe %r10 "arguments 1 through 10," so perhaps the book isn't explaining clearly, or I am misunderstanding the meaning? Would you mind talking about (in a non-comment answer, perhaps) what the book might mean by "return value" and "arguments," or perhaps explaining what the actual concept behind these are? Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's true *at function boundaries* (args before a call / at top of a function, RAX (and also RDX for wide integers / structs) = retval at the bottom of a function, at the ret / or in the caller after a call).  Where you're going wrong is continuing to assign that meaning *within* a function, when they're actually just being used as scratch registers.

Comment: However, x86-64 System V only passes up to 6 integer args in registers, RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9, not 10 args.  R10 is used to pass a "static chain" pointer for languages that have nested functions that can access their parent function's local vars, but in C and C++ it's just a call-clobbered register like R11. 
 [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](//stackoverflow.com/q/18024672) shows an extract from the ABI doc.  [What's the best way to remember the x86-64 System V arg register order?](//stackoverflow.com/q/63891991) describes why it's designed that way